# Cannot Find the Reported APM Logs on the Huawei Devices

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, apm, appgallery-connect

When the Huawei APM SDK is integrated, there was no app performance data on the App performance management page. I wanted to locate the problem based on the Logcat logs on the device.

However, I'm not sure where these logs are kept or if I have to enable them in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the [APM documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-apms-viewlog) and found out how to access the logs:

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file of the app, and add the meta-data element to the application.

```
<application>  
    <meta-data 
      android:name="apms_debug_log_enabled" 
      android:value=" true" /> 
</application>
```

After the APM debug log function is enabled, you can use the Logcat log filter function `com.huawei.agc.apms` or `apms` to view the logs.